# Replace non-reactive data with reactive data

Tags: r, shiny

I have a complicated shiny app where I have used '<-' to create new columns on a non-reactive data.something like:

```
# Without reactive expression
ui <- fluidPage(tableOutput("contents"))
server1 <- function(input, output) {

  myData <- mtcars
  myData$New1 <- rep("NV1", nrow(myData))
  myData$New2 <- rep("NV2", nrow(myData))
  myData$New3 <- rep("NV3", nrow(myData))
  myData$New4 <- rep("NV4", nrow(myData))

  output$contents <- renderTable(myData)
}

shinyApp(ui, server1)
```

Now I want to replace the non-reactive data with reactive. How can I do that with minimal change?
I have tried something like:

```
# With reactive expression
ui <- fluidPage(tableOutput("contents"))

server2 <- function(input, output) {

  all <- reactiveValues()
  all$d <- mtcars

  all$d$New1 <- rep("NV1", nrow(all$d))
  all$d$New2 <- rep("NV2", nrow(all$d))
  all$d$New3 <- rep("NV3", nrow(all$d))
  all$d$New4 <- rep("NV4", nrow(all$d))

  output$contents <- renderTable(all$d)
}

shinyApp(ui, server2)
```

Comment: You can't work with reactive values like that in non-reactive environment. So, in other words - do that in `observe()`, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(tableOutput("contents"))

server2 <- function(input, output) {

  # you can assign variables in reactiveValues(), no need to make a new line
  all <- reactiveValues(d = mtcars) 

  observeEvent(all$d, { # update all$d, after it is created
  req(!is.null(all$d))

  all$d$New1 <- rep("NV1", nrow(all$d))
  all$d$New2 <- rep("NV2", nrow(all$d))
  all$d$New3 <- rep("NV3", nrow(all$d))
  all$d$New4 <- rep("NV4", nrow(all$d))
})
  output$contents <- renderTable(all$d)
}
```

Comment: Good. If that answers your question, consider [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: In some place of the code I have **d <- reactive(mtcars)** instead of **all <- reactiveValues(d = mtcars)**. What to do in that case?

Comment: Just use `d()` instead of `all$d`

Comment: That is throwing the following error: Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
  [No stack trace available]

Comment: Something is trying to access your variable, but it doesn't hold the data in it yet. (probably, the `d <- reactive(mtcars)` happens after the piece of code that generates an error). Find that place and put a `req(!is.null(yourVar)))` there, so it won't run until the variable is not null.